# Suddenly receiving GmailApp.SendEmail error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

experts!

I'm faced with a question that has no answer, so I'm reaching out for help. Thanks in advance to anybody that can make sense of this.

I made a script (triggered weekly) that converts a Google sheet into a pdf, then attaches it to an email and sends it off. It's been working fine for months, now suddenly won't save or run. I'm getting the error "Invalid argument: fileName (line 80, file "Code")" (The "GmailApp.sendEmail" line is line 80.) As expected, the web didn't shed much light on why this is happening, or how to fix it.

Any ideas to throw my way?

Here is the relevant code. (GAS is flagging the "GmailApp.sendEmail" line as an error.)

```
     // Sets the recipient(s) of the email message
     var emailAddress1 = srcSheet1.getRange('J299').getValue();
    
     // Sets the subject of the email message
     var emailSubject1 = srcSheet1.getRange('C12').getValue();

     // Sets the 'body message' of the email message
     var emailBodyMessage1 = srcSheet1.getRange('C54').getValue();
     
     // This section converts the new sheet into a pdf blob

     // Make the pdf
     var blob1 = DriveApp.getFileById(srcSpreadsheet1.getId()).getAs("application/pdf");

     // Set the title of the pdf
     var PDFsubject1 = srcSheet1.getRange('C54').getValue() + ".pdf";
     blob1.setName(PDFsubject1);
     
     // This section assembles and sends the email
     
     GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress1,emailSubject1,emailBodyMessage1, {
          htmlBody: emailBodyMessage1,
          attachments:[blob1]     
          });
```

Comment: In the example here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options they uses 'MimeType.PDF'. I would try it.

Comment: Elchanan shucky Shukrun - Thank you for your suggestion, but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Not sure but check the value of `srcSheet1.getRange('C54').getValue()`

Comment: I changed the "GmailApp.sendEmail" line to be: GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient1,emailSubject1, 'Please see the attached file.', {
       attachments: [blob1.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]});

Comment: Rocky - Any idea what I need to look for in cell C54?

Comment: @user3279926 should be valid file name

Comment: Is `srcSpreadsheet1` somewhere defined ? you don't provide it in the script.

Answer (score 2):

```
var emailBodyMessage1 = srcSheet1.getRange('C54').getValue();
```

```
var PDFsubject1 = srcSheet1.getRange('C54').getValue() + ".pdf";
```

There is something wrong with the cell 'C54'. You're getting a body of the message and a file name from this cell. And at some point the content of the cells was changed into something that can't be a file name. Perhaps the cell now contains line breaks or tab symbols and the like.

Comment: Thanks, Yuri - You were right. (Thanks to Rocky, too.) There WAS something wrong with cell C54. I rewrote the cell, removing anything that might not be text or a number converted to text, and now everything works as intended!

To all - Thank you for your valuable info and assistance!

Answer (score 1):

This is an example that works perfectly

```
function myFunction() {

  var myEmail = 'xxxxxx@gmail.com'
  var blob1 = DriveApp.getFileById('1IsP2bETUE-d2RZakxbkuASSCZYdSaUCk3uAFstFdIWM').getAs("application/pdf")
  blob1.setName('test pdf file');
  GmailApp.sendEmail(myEmail, 'test pdf', 'test', {
      htmlBody: '<b>test</b>',
      attachments: [blob1]
    });

}
```

I recommand to check any individual term in your script :

```
Logger.log(srcSpreadsheet1.getId())
Logger.log(emailAddress1)
Logger.log(emailSubject1)
Logger.log(emailBodyMessage1)
```